# integral $\int \sqrt{x^4+x^3} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\int \sqrt{x^4+x^3} \, dx?
$$

Using the binomial method and by setting $\frac{1}{x}+1=t$, I get to solve

$$
\int \frac{-t^{\frac{3}{2}}}{(t^2-1)^4} dt? 
$$
It is on degree $\frac 32$. How to solve this it seems a bit hard and impossible.

Comment: What about $dt$ and $dx$?

Comment: Are you solving between 0 and 1? Or are you doing an indefinite integral?

Comment: indefinite integral

Comment: dx and them becomes dt

Answer (score 11):

HINT: $\sqrt{x^4+x^3}=x^{3/2}\sqrt{x+1}$. If $u=\sqrt{x+1}$, then $x=u^2-1$, so $dx=2u\,du$.

Comment: Nice, and straight forward :) +1

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \sqrt{x^4 + x^3} \;dx = \int x\sqrt{x^2 + x}\;dx = \frac{1}{2} \int (2x+1)\sqrt{x^2+x}\;dx - \frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{x^2 + x} \;dx \\
= \frac{1}{2} \int (2x+1)\sqrt{x^2+x}\;dx - \frac{1}{2} \int \sqrt{\left( x + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2-\frac{1}{4}} \;dx $$

For the first term, substitute $t = x^2 + x$. For the second term, substitute $x + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\cosh u$